# php array_shift vs unset in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, unset

Hi what is the difference between array_shift and unset in associative array?

I understand how in a normal array, if you use array_shift, the key is still there and only the first value goes away but in associative array, I don't see any difference between array_shift and unset.

below is the code example:

```
    $a=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
    $key=key($a);
    unset($a[$key]);
    print_r ($a);

    //result: Array ( [b] => green [c] => blue )

    $b=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
    array_shift($b);
    print_r ($b);

    //result: Array ( [b] => green [c] => blue )
```

Comment: `array_shift()` is specifically for *shifting* the element off the beginning of the array, and returning it. `unset()` *unsets* a variable. read the documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: You're right, both versions achieve the same things. Sometimes there are several ways to achieve one result.

Comment: But what is the best way? My feeling is that with array_shift I could save a step to get the data and clean it from the array. If you don't want the first data, with unset you can do it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_shift` will return the head of your array (in this instance entry "a")

while `unset` will remove an element by its key, say `unset($a['b'])` will leave you with `Array ( [a] => red [c] => blue )`